# SQL Statement to Find Out Which Schema Owns an Oracle Table?

Tags: sql, oracle, schema

What is a SQL statement to find out which Schema owns an Oracle table?

Comment: Did you google your question? You'll find the answer in 10 secs.

Comment: I was trying to see who owned the `USER_TABLES`. The SQL I found did not help with this table, and so far the answers don't work with this table, but they work with all normal user tables.

Comment: USER_TABLES is not a table but a dictionary view. See by answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see information about any object in the database, in your case USER_TABLES use:

```
select * from all_objects where object_name = 'USER_TABLES';

OWNER OBJECT_NAME       OBJECT_ID   OBJECT_TYPE   CREATED   LAST_DDL_TIME
SYS   USER_TABLES       3922        VIEW          24-MAY-13 24-MAY-13
```

USER_TABLES is a dictionary view. All dictionary views are owned by SYS.

Comment: Thank you! The name  'USER_TABLES' made me think it was a table.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT OWNER FROM DBA_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<your table>'`

If you don't have privilege to `DBA_TABLES` use `ALL_TABLES`.

Comment: This did work for all normal user tables. How to see who owns the `USER_TABLES`. Because I wanted to view this table in Toad for Oracle but don't know who owns it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the queries:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='<TABLE_NAME>'; -- There is no owner column in this view
SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER='<OWNER_NAME>' AND TABLE_NAME='<TABLE_NAME>';
SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME FROM DBA_TABLES WHERE OWNER='<OWNER_NAME>' AND TABLE_NAME='<TABLE_NAME>';
```

Also you can query USER_OBJECTS, ALL_OBJECTS, DBA_OBJECTS using `OBJECT_TYPE='TABLE' and OWNER= '<OWNER_NAME>' and OBJECT_NAME='<TABLE_NAME>'`

There are 3 views, which can give that information:

- USER_TABLES, if the login schema is the owner of the table
- ALL_TABLES, if the login schema have permission on the table or owner of the table or have SELECT_CATALOG role
- DBA_TABLES, if the login schema have SELECT_CATALOG role or any other role which have SELECT_CATALOG role